# É possível alterar mais de um registro de uma vez?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where

Esse é o código:

```
UPDATE PESSOAS
SET COR = ('Pardo')
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Porém tenho mais 2 registros para fazer o mesmo procedimento, daria para fazer tudo de uma só vez acrescentando o `ID`?

Comment: Ramon, qual o tipo de dado que essa coluna armazena. Poderia compartilhar as informações da estrutura dessa tabela, para um melhor entendimento da sua pergunta

Comment: basta que os outros registros entrem na condição do `WHERE` como Maniero postou

Comment: Caique segue a estrutura:

CREATE TABLE PESSOAS (

ID            INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NOME          VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
NASCIMENTO    DATE,
SEXO          CHAR (1),
PROFISSÃO     VARCHAR (15),
PESO          DECIMAL (5,2),
ALTURA        DECIMAL(3,2),
NACIONALIDADE VARCHAR (10) DEFAULT 'Brasil',
              PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

Ai eu usei o ALTER TABLE + ADD COLUMN para adicionar uma nova coluna, a de "COR". Com isso, eu gostaria de preencher esse campo que se encontra vazio em todos os registros de uma só vez.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basta dizer na cláusula `WHERE` que deseja fazer em vários, poderia usar um `OR` para selecionar vários `ID`s, mas acho que neste caso seja mais apropriado o uso do [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html).

```
UPDATE PESSOAS
SET COR = ('Pardo')
WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/MultipleIn.sql).

Comment: Seria isso, mas tentei dessa forma que você passou porém não alterou, a mensagem que retornou foi a seguinte:

16:03:34 UPDATE PESSOAS SET COR = ('Pardo') WHERE ID = (1,2,3) Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s) 0.000 sec

Comment: @RamonAlmeida Você trocou o **=** por `IN`? Veja no código do Maniero que o segredo é justamente o `IN`.

Comment: Não me atentei ao detalhe, deu certo aqui!!

Obrigado pessoal, de verdade, ajudaram muito!!